# Проблема header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

Tags: nginx, изображения, php, header, ubuntu

Здравствуйте.

Странная проблема: движок перенес на другой хостинг - и следующий код перестал работать:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');  
readfile('photo.jpg');
```

На выходе получаю битую картинку. До переноса все прекрасно работало, проблем с путями нет, с заглавными буквами в путях тоже нет, доступ к папке с картинками 777. Версия php 5.6. Куда рыть?

Если закомментировать функцию **header**, то кракозябру я получаю.

Comment: Загляните любым вьювером, хоть Windows Notepad внутрь битого файла. Там может оказаться осмысленный текст - сообщение об ошибке PHP. А если нет, то сравните визуально первые символы с тем как это выглядит в нормальном jpg.

Answer (score 2):

Сравни заголовки которые отдаются при обращению к скрипту и непосредственно к картинке

```
curl -I http://site/path/to/script

curl -I http://site/path/to/image
```

Answer (score -1):

Удостоверься в соответствии включенности gzip с наличием соответствующего заголовка. Скорее всего, ты отправляешь сжатый файл, а заголовок не выставляешь. Но и обратный вариант тоже возможен.

Comment: За что минусы-то?

Comment: Нападение злых анонимных минусаторов.